# Convert NSURL to local file path

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an NSURL that looks like this:

```
file://localhost/Users/myuser/myfile.txt
```

Is there a standard function to convert it to a local file path looking like this:

```
/Users/myuser/myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Use the `-[NSURL path]` method:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myUrl.path);
```

From the documentation:

> The path of the URL, unescaped with the `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method. If the receiver does not conform to RFC 1808, returns `nil`.
>
> If this URL object contains a file URL (as determined with `isFileURL`), the return value of this method is suitable for input into methods of NSFileManager or NSPathUtilities. If the path has a trailing slash it is stripped.
>
> Per RFC 3986, the leading slash after the authority (host name and port) portion is treated as part of the path.

Note that you can create such a URL with `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`.

Comment: Depending where you get the URL from, you may want to check `[myURL isFileURL]` is true.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4:**

```
absoluteURL.path
```

or

```
yourUrl.path
```