# How get file size with url?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application I need to get the file size, but I have only url of it.

If I have file path I can get size like this:

```
NSDictionary* attributeDict = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:resourcePath error:nil];
NSNumber* fileSizeObj = [attributeDict objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSizeVal = [fileSizeObj longLongValue];
```

How can I correctly get file size if I have url ?

Comment: you can convert URL to Path [NSURL path] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956325/converting-a-nsurl-to-a-local-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NSURLConnection` with `Head` request, the response will have [expectedContentLength](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

Request

```
NSMutableURLRequest * req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"Head"];
NSURLConnection * con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req
                                                    delegate:self];
[con start];
[con release];
```

Delegate

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse (%lld)", response.expectedContentLength);
}
```

Note it might be negative:

```
#define NSURLResponseUnknownLength ((long long)-1)
```

For `NSURLSession`, use tasks factory methods that are accepting `NSURLRequest` objects as parameters, e.g. `- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler:`

Comment: How could a filesize be negative?

Comment: Nerrolken, it can't and that's the point, we can safely use the constant negative value and be sure that it means what is should mean: *Unknown* size.

Comment: @A-Live Is there a way to do this with `NSURLSession`? Since `NSURLConnection` is now deprecated.

Comment: @NSGangster you need to create a task from the request and then use the task within your session, see the updated answer.