# Attach Image to Email in React Native (using rn-image-picker & rn-mail)

Tags: ios, email, react-native, email-attachments

**11/04 UPDATE:**

I've created a repo with an app that demonstrates just this problem below. Anyone who wants to install and play with it can find it here...
https://github.com/geirman/react-native-photo-emailer

---

I'm using the following packages together in an attempt to choose an image from the gallery (or take one using the camera), then attach that photo to an email.

- [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker)
- [react-native-mail](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail)

The following code works great on Android, but fails to attach the image on iOS.

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
handleAndroid = (subject, to) => {
  var pickerOptions = {
    title: 'Select Avatar',
    storageOptions: {
      skipBackup: true,
      path: 'images'
    }
  };

  ImagePicker.showImagePicker(pickerOptions, (response) => {
    const { uri, type, path } = response;
    this.sendMail(subject, to, path, type);
  });
}
```

And the sendMail method looks like this (minus error handling to simplify)

```
import Mailer from 'react-native-mail';
sendMail = (subject, to, uri, type) => {
  Mailer.mail({
    subject,
    recipients: [to],
    body: 'Optional Comment: ',
    attachment: {
      path: uri,
      type: type,
      name: subject
    },
    isHTML: true
  }
}
```

Note that `attachment.path` must be the full file path to the attachment. For Android, that turns out to be the `response.path`, but iOS only returns `response.uri`.

For iOS's sendMail method, I remove `attachment.name` and `attachment.type` since they aren't returned, leaving just `attachment.path` which is set to the `response.uri`.

#### `response.path` (on Android) looks like this (***this works***)...

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20171102_11304344.jpg
```

#### `response.uri` (on iOS) looks like this (`response.path` does not return anything on iOS)...

```
file://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/983938D-5304-463C-BD05-D033E55F5BEB/Documents/images/224CA6DD-5299-48C3-A7CF-0B645004535F.jpg
```

#### But according to [React native - send photo per mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141637/react-native-send-photo-per-mail/38182998#38182998), I want something that looks more like this (on iOS)...

```
/Users/anton/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9A15F203-9A58-41C5-A4FC-EA25FAAE92BD/data/Containers/Data/Application/79FF93F9-BA89-4F4C-8809-277BEECD447D/Documents/EFFF0ECE-4063-4FE5-984E-E76506788350.jpg
```

So my question is, how do I get the full path to the image on iOS from the above the `response.uri` value. In other words, how do I get something that looks more like what RNMail needs (e.g. `/Users/anton...`) from what ImagePicker returns (e.g. `file://var/mobile...`)?

### Update:

I forgot to mention that I'm running these tests on actual devices. An Android Moto Z and iPhone 5s. This is necessary because emulators are useless when testing camera and email functionality.

Here's a dump of my xcode logs related to one session: initialize app > choose photo from gallery > email opens (nothing attached) > cancel > delete draft (throws an 'email failed to send' error, even if I send it I get this error though the email does actually send)

```
2017-11-02 20:12:45.310 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:187] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x1c01b5fc0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x1c00babe0>, executor: (null))
2017-11-02 20:12:45.314031-0700 RNMail[434:92814] Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x1c01b5fc0> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x1c00babe0>, executor: (null))
2017-11-02 20:12:45.421 [warn][tid:main][RCTBridge.m:121] Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
2017-11-02 20:12:45.421568-0700 RNMail[434:92814] Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
2017-11-02 20:12:45.492 [warn][tid:main][RCTModuleData.mm:69] Module RNMail requires main queue setup since it overrides `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
2017-11-02 20:12:45.492054-0700 RNMail[434:92814] Module RNMail requires main queue setup since it overrides `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.
2017-11-02 20:12:45.504 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:301] Running application RNMail ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2017-11-02 20:12:45.503900-0700 RNMail[434:92814] Running application RNMail ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2017-11-02 20:12:45.537105-0700 RNMail[434:92814] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 0
2017-11-02 20:12:45.537237-0700 RNMail[434:92814] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2017-11-02 20:12:45.537355-0700 RNMail[434:92814] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 434, TID: 92857, Thread name: com.facebook.react.JavaScript, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   RNMail                              0x000000010026d2bc RCTCurrentAppBackgroundState + 220
5   RNMail                              0x000000010026c7f8 -[RCTAppState constantsToExport] + 68
6   RNMail                              0x0000000100275af4 -[RCTModuleData gatherConstants] + 724
7   RNMail                              0x0000000100275ea8 -[RCTModuleData exportedConstants] + 36
8   RNMail                              0x00000001002d312c _ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule12getConstantsEv + 216
9   RNMail                              0x000000010035764c _ZN8facebook5react14ModuleRegistry9getConfigERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE + 5864
10  RNMail                              0x000000010038d8e0 _ZN8facebook5react16JSCNativeModules12createModuleERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEPK15OpaqueJSContext + 492
11  RNMail                              0x000000010038c5a0 _ZN8facebook5react16JSCNativeModules9getModuleEPK15OpaqueJSContextP14OpaqueJSString + 640
12  RNMail                              0x00000001003708c0 _ZN8facebook5react11JSCExecutor15getNativeModuleEP13OpaqueJSValueP14OpaqueJSString + 268
13  RNMail                              0x000000010037313c _ZZN8facebook5react12_GLOBAL__N_119exceptionWrapMethodIXadL_ZNS0_11JSCExecutor15getNativeModuleEP13OpaqueJSValueP14OpaqueJSStringEEEEPFPKS4_PK15OpaqueJSContextS5_S7_PS9_EvEN11funcWrapper4callESC_S5_S7_SD_ + 356
14  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018df6cdc4 <redacted> + 336
15  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018d950394 <redacted> + 3952
16  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e052a94 <redacted> + 10612
17  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
18  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
19  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
20  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
21  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
22  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
23  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
24  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e04ff50 <redacted> + 272
25  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018df35b94 <redacted> + 136
26  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018df0cb28 <redacted> + 11244
27  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018dc011ac _ZN3JSC8evaluateEPNS_9ExecStateERKNS_10SourceCodeENS_7JSValueERN3WTF8NakedPtrINS_9ExceptionEEE + 316
28  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018df6a558 JSEvaluateScript + 448
29  RNMail                              0x00000001002fcc58 _ZN8facebook5react14evaluateScriptEPK15OpaqueJSContextP14OpaqueJSStringS5_ + 100
30  RNMail                              0x000000010036d494 _ZN8facebook5react11JSCExecutor21loadApplicationScriptENSt3__110unique_ptrIKNS0_11JSBigStringENS2_14default_deleteIS5_EEEENS2_12basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE + 2528
31  RNMail                              0x0000000100384d14 _ZZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge15loadApplicationENSt3__110unique_ptrINS0_17JSModulesUnbundleENS2_14default_deleteIS4_EEEENS3_IKNS0_11JSBigStringENS5_IS9_EEEENS2_12basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEN3$_0clEPNS0_10JSExecutorE + 1372
32  RNMail                              0x00000001003847ac _ZNSt3__128__invoke_void_return_wrapperIvE6__callIJRZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge15loadApplicationENS_10unique_ptrINS4_17JSModulesUnbundleENS_14default_deleteIS7_EEEENS6_IKNS4_11JSBigStringENS8_ISC_EEEENS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEE3$_0PNS4_10JSExecutorEEEEvDpOT_ + 84
33  RNMail                              0x0000000100383da0 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN8fa2017-11-02 20:12:46.253004-0700 RNMail[434:92857] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 434, TID: 92857, Thread name: com.facebook.react.JavaScript, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   RNMail                              0x000000010026d2bc RCTCurrentAppBackgroundState + 220
5   RNMail                              0x000000010026c7f8 -[RCTAppState constantsToExport] + 68
6   RNMail                              0x0000000100275af4 -[RCTModuleData gatherConstants] + 724
7   RNMail                              0x0000000100275ea8 -[RCTModuleData exportedConstants] + 36
8   RNMail                              0x00000001002d312c _ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule12getConstantsEv + 216
9   RNMail                              0x000000010035764c _ZN8facebook5react14ModuleRegistry9getConfigERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE + 5864
10  RNMail                              0x000000010038d8e0 _ZN8facebook5react16JSCNativeModules12createModuleERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEPK15OpaqueJSContext + 492
11  RNMail                              0x000000010038c5a0 _ZN8facebook5react16JSCNativeModules9getModuleEPK15OpaqueJSContextP14OpaqueJSString + 640
12  RNMail                              0x00000001003708c0 _ZN8facebook5react11JSCExecutor15getNativeModuleEP13OpaqueJSValueP14OpaqueJSString + 268
13  RNMail                              0x000000010037313c _ZZN8facebook5react12_GLOBAL__N_119exceptionWrapMethodIXadL_ZNS0_11JSCExecutor15getNativeModuleEP13OpaqueJSValueP14OpaqueJSStringEEEEPFPKS4_PK15OpaqueJSContextS5_S7_PS9_EvEN11funcWrapper4callESC_S5_S7_SD_ + 356
14  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018df6cdc4 <redacted> + 336
15  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018d950394 <redacted> + 3952
16  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e052a94 <redacted> + 10612
17  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
18  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
19  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
20  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
21  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
22  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
23  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e056a94 <redacted> + 26996
24  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018e04ff50 <redacted> + 272
25  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018df35b94 <redacted> + 136
26  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018df0cb28 <redacted> + 11244
27  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018dc011ac _ZN3JSC8evaluateEPNS_9ExecStateERKNS_10SourceCodeENS_7JSValueERN3WTF8NakedPtrINS_9ExceptionEEE + 316
28  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000018df6a558 JSEvaluateScript + 448
29  RNMail                              0x00000001002fcc58 _ZN8facebook5react14evaluateScriptEPK15OpaqueJSContextP14OpaqueJSStringS5_ + 100
30  RNMail                              0x000000010036d494 _ZN8facebook5react11JSCExecutor21loadApplicationScriptENSt3__110unique_ptrIKNS0_11JSBigStringENS2_14default_deleteIS5_EEEENS2_12basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE + 2528
31  RNMail                              0x0000000100384d14 _ZZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge15loadApplicationENSt3__110unique_ptrINS0_17JSModulesUnbundleENS2_14default_deleteIS4_EEEENS3_IKNS0_11JSBigStringENS5_IS9_EEEENS2_12basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEN3$_0clEPNS0_10JSExecutorE + 1372
32  RNMail                              0x00000001003847ac _ZNSt3__128__invoke_void_return_wrapperIvE6__callIJRZN8facebook5react16NativeToJsBridge15loadApplicationENS_10unique_ptrINS4_17JSModulesUnbundleENS_14default_deleteIS7_EEEENS6_IKNS4_11JSBigStringENS8_ISC_EEEENS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEEE3$_0PNS4_10JSExecutorEEEEvDpOT_ + 84
33  RNMail                              0x0000000100383da0 _ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN8fa
2017-11-02 20:12:46.621 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Running application "RNMail" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2017-11-02 20:12:46.621391-0700 RNMail[434:92857] Running application "RNMail" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2017-11-02 20:12:47.742027-0700 RNMail[434:92844] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 4 Connection has no connected handler
2017-11-02 20:12:47.742187-0700 RNMail[434:92844] TCP Conn 0x1c4170200 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2017-11-02 20:12:50.900283-0700 RNMail[434:92848] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 5 Connection has no connected handler
2017-11-02 20:12:50.900432-0700 RNMail[434:92848] TCP Conn 0x1c0171400 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2017-11-02 20:12:53.627866-0700 RNMail[434:92814] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-11-02 20:12:53.628903-0700 RNMail[434:92814] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2017-11-02 20:12:54.060535-0700 RNMail[434:92843] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 6 Connection has no connected handler
2017-11-02 20:12:54.060707-0700 RNMail[434:92843] TCP Conn 0x1c416e400 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2017-11-02 20:12:57.279004-0700 RNMail[434:92847] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 7 Connection has no connected handler
2017-11-02 20:12:57.279148-0700 RNMail[434:92847] TCP Conn 0x1c0172b40 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2017-11-02 20:13:00.409536-0700 RNMail[434:92848] [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
2017-11-02 20:13:00.429314-0700 RNMail[434:93038] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 8 Connection has no connected handler
2017-11-02 20:13:00.429401-0700 RNMail[434:93038] TCP Conn 0x1c0171c40 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2017-11-02 20:13:00.827 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'Response = ', { fileSize: 508257,
  data: REMOVED_BASE64_STRING
  timestamp: '2017-10-25T02:51:35Z',
  uri: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/144D1C48-C6D5-475A-891A-F75360CD64E2/Documents/images/0EF09235-6E04-4799-86F5-3E996ED4E439.jpg',
  origURL: 'assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=EF345E7A-2DF1-49CA-875D-4208976A635B&ext=JPG',
  isVertical: false,
  height: 768,
  width: 1024,
  fileName: 'IMG_0003.JPG' }
2017-11-02 20:13:00.888025-0700 RNMail[434:92857] 'Response = ', { fileSize: 508257,
  data: REMOVED_BASE64_STRING
2017-11-02 20:13:00.974189-0700 RNMail[434:92814] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: org.reactjs.native.example.RNMail, source account management: 1
2017-11-02 20:13:00.985481-0700 RNMail[434:92814] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: org.reactjs.native.example.RNMail, source account management: 1
2017-11-02 20:13:01.834117-0700 RNMail[434:92814] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-11-02 20:13:01.843828-0700 RNMail[434:92814] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-11-02 20:13:04.218796-0700 RNMail[434:93034] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 9 Connection has no connected handler
2017-11-02 20:13:04.218943-0700 RNMail[434:93034] TCP Conn 0x1c01747c0 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2017-11-02 20:13:07.341962-0700 RNMail[434:93036] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 10 Connection has no connected handler
2017-11-02 20:13:07.342107-0700 RNMail[434:93036] TCP Conn 0x1c0172540 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2017-11-02 20:13:08.605 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] null
2017-11-02 20:13:08.606476-0700 RNMail[434:92857] null
2017-11-02 20:13:10.469212-0700 RNMail[434:93034] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 11 Connection has no connected handler
2017-11-02 20:13:10.469352-0700 RNMail[434:93034] TCP Conn 0x1c4174280 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2017-11-02 20:13:11.144 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] OK: Email Error Response
2017-11-02 20:13:11.144088-0700 RNMail[434:92857] OK: Email Error Response
2017-11-02 20:13:13.599247-0700 RNMail[434:93036] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket 12 Connection has no connected handler
2017-11-02 20:13:13.599391-0700 RNMail[434:93036] TCP Conn 0x1c0175480 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
```

---

**Update 11/7/2017**

At @Artal's suggestion, I started digging into the Xcode debugger. I found that the `attachmentPath` is assigned to `fileData` as an `NSData` type, then it's later used to actually attach the photo to the email. However, while it looks as though fileData is being assigned properly, as soon as I step one line further into the code, then `fileData = nill` somehow. Here's a few screenshots that step through the code.

[image]

Comment: The link you are attaching is MacOS not iOS, different OS so path won't necessary be the same. What error are you getting?

Comment: Hey @sfratini, thanks for the reply. I'm running these on actual devices since they use camera and email, making the emulators useless. I should have mentioned that. So, the `response.uri` is what I'm getting from an actual iPhone 5s. I'll update the question with a dump of the logs.

Comment: Hace you tried with origUrl?

Comment: origURL doesn't work either

Comment: I had a similar question once which was resolved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141637/react-native-send-photo-per-mail  - it's old but maybe there are a few insights that might help

Comment: Yes @noa-dev, I've seen it. I even reference it in my question. Thx tho

Comment: Looking at the module code, your file:// path is OK. At this point I think I would just open an issue with the module. Another thing I am wondering is if iOS does not let you access that file unless the app is published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Artal set me on the right path, but this is the code that ultimately solved the problem...

[Replace Line 82 of RNMail.m](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail/blob/master/RNMail/RNMail.m#L82)

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:attachmentPath];
```

With this code...

```
// Get the URL string, which is *not* a path (e.g. because it's file:// based)
NSString *attachmentURLString = [RCTConvert NSString:options[@"attachment"][@"path"]];
// Create a URL from the string
NSURL *attachmentURL = [[NSURLComponents componentsWithString:attachmentURLString] URL];

// Get the resource path and read the file using NSData
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:attachmentURL options:0 error:&error];

if(fileData == nil) {
    // handle error
}
```

More information surrounding how this solution was arrived at, please see [NSData Assignment Vanishes (becomes nil) Directly After Assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170739/nsdata-assignment-vanishes-becomes-nil-directly-after-assigned#47170815)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it to work! It still seems to me that you could get it done without having to change the native code of an external package you’re using, which can be a pain in the long run... maybe the file url that you were sending still required modifications (or maybe you have already removed the url transformation?). in any way, at least you have one working solution :)

Comment: Yeah, I hear you on it not being ideal to change the external package. If you have other thoughts I should be investigating, I'd love to hear them. At least now I have something working though (for now)

Comment: The only thoughts is as I said, understand the correct url that this package will accept. If you had a full working example I might be able to try and help, but yeah - at least you have a working solution

Comment: Thanks, It's working like charm in iOS, but what about Android?

Comment: It also works in Android. Here's a working example https://github.com/geirman/react-native-photo-emailer

Comment: So we have to use rn-mail for iOS and rn-photo-emailer for android? we can not use the same rn-mail for android?

Comment: @KAUSHALJ.SATHWARA, no...the example uses [react-native-mail](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail)

Comment: In iOS attachment successfully with your above answer. but in Android, I'm getting 'Unable to attach file' toast.
My android code:

 attachment: {
                       
path:'http://112.196.33.86:8080/demo/inicio/img/propertiesphotos/2018-12-13-6184.png',  
 type: 'png',
 name: 'Ladunek',   
                },

Answer (score 1):

`react-native-mail` is using the `NSData` method `dataWithContentsOfFile` to create the attachment data for the email from the `path` parameter that you're providing (see [here](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail/blob/master/RNMail/RNMail.m#L82)). [dataWithContentsOfFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1547226-datawithcontentsoffile) receives an absolute, string-based path, and not a path-based file URL like the one you're trying to use.

The "correct" path you provided with `/Users/anton/Library/Developer...` is a local path when used on a simulator. On a real device, you can expect it to look similar to the file path you provided which resides in your app's sandboxed Documents folder. The `origURL` by the way is a url to an internal assets library database which you can not load directly.

Simply removing the `file:/` scheme from the string should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks so much @Artal. I had a similar thought but hadn't tried it yet. I was glad to read your suggestion, but unfortunately that didn't work. Here's a console.log of `uri` and `_uri` where `_uri` is the transformed version. 

`2017-11-04 08:16:13.664099-0700 photoEmailer[784:639288] {
  "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BB67334B-9193-4992-8FAC-CD2806C1D335/Documents/images/F7D90920-8268-4EEB-8C02-D870C34CEDA1.jpg",
  "_uri": "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BB67334B-9193-4992-8FAC-CD2806C1D335/Documents/images/F7D90920-8268-4EEB-8C02-D870C34CEDA1.jpg"`
}

Comment: That’s weird, maybe something else is going on there. My suggestion - run your app with Xcode, put a breakpoint where it creates the data from path on the native side (the line I sent as a reference), and see what happens. Are you getting the expected path? Are you getting nil when trying to create the NSData?

Comment: Thanks @Artal, that was helpful. I hadn't worked in the Xcode debugger before. I learned that I was never getting to that breakpoint because I wasn't passing in the required `type`. Now that I am, I'm stuck at another point though. The email never even launches because I get stuck at this error: [EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x1011bf11c)](https://screencast.com/t/Lutsea5lV). No idea what that means. If I remove the `type` I get an email without attachment. And [this is what my method call looks like now](https://screencast.com/t/ZgWgJKzBp4r)

Comment: I've updated my question with screenshots of the debug session. It appears as though on line 77, the variable `fileData` is being assigned an NSData object fine, but in the very next line (80) it becomes nil. If you have any ideas why that might be, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

I’m using the base64 content of the picture instead of the url. Probably you can create an attachment with the same base64 content, after all that’s how email attachments work anyway

Comment: The thought crossed my mind, but as far as I can tell, the mail api only takes the fill path. If you know how to work around this, please show some code