# NSData Assignment Vanishes (becomes nil) Directly After Assigned

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let me start by saying I'm not proficient in objective c, nor am I an iOS developer. I'm working on a react-native app and find that I'm having to dig into the native code. So, I appreciate your patience with me and would also very much appreciate if you made zero assumptions about what I might, or might not know. Thx!

I'm trying to use [react-native-mail](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail/) but it fails to attach the photo I've selected to the email.

In troubleshooting, I jumped into Xcode's debugger for the first time. Stepping through the code, it appears as though the `attachmentPath` which is something like `file:///var/mobile/...` is being assigned to the variable `fileData` as type `NSData`. But then, taking one step further into the code it becomes `nil`.

I'm not sure why this would happen nor how to go about troubleshooting this. Here's an image of the debugger session with 3 screenshots stitched together side-by-side.

[**Here's the code: RNMail.m**](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail/blob/master/RNMail/RNMail.m)

All pointers, tips, guidance, and advice welcome

[image]

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled? And if you ignore what the sidebar shows and in the debugger run `po fileData`, what do you get?

Comment: I'm not even sure how to know how I'm compiling. How would I tell? Also, where do I run the `po fileData` command?  I see a filter box, but that's not it

Comment: Please do not post a link to your code, copy and paste the actual (relevant) code into your question, as text.

Comment: @maddy, I understand what you mean but in this case the link to the code was extra and would have just cluttered the question. I added it just in case someone wanted more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first screenshot, the debugger is still on the line that declares and assigns the `fileData` variable. This means that that line hasn't actually been executed yet. `-dataWithContentsOfFile:` hasn't yet been called, and thus the value that appears to be in `fileData` is not meaningful; what you're seeing is just garbage data prior to the variable actually being assigned. In your second screenshot, the `-dataWithContentsOfFile:` method has finished running, and it has returned `nil`. What you need to do is to figure out why you're getting `nil` from `-dataWithContentsOfFile:`. Perhaps the path to the file is incorrect, or perhaps you don't have permission to read it, or perhaps you have a sandboxing issue.

I would suggest using `-dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` instead of `-dataWithContentsOfFile:`. This will return an error by reference (create an `NSError` variable ahead of time, assign it to `nil`, pass a pointer to the error as the third parameter to `-dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`, and then check the error if the method returns `nil`). More likely than not, the contents of the error will explain what went wrong when trying to read the file.

EDIT: Looking at your screenshot again, the problem is clear; from the description of the contents of `attachmentPath`, we can see that it isn't a path at all, but instead it contains a URL string (with scheme `file:`). So you cannot pass it to the APIs that use paths. This is okay, since the URL-based mechanisms are what Apple recommends using anyway. So, just turn it into a URL by passing the string to `-[NSURL URLWithString:]` (or, even better, `-[[NSURLComponents componentsWithString:] URL]`, since it conforms to a newer RFC). So, something like:

```
// Get the URL string, which is *not* a path
NSString *attachmentURLString = [RCTConvert NSString:options[@"attachment"][@"path"]];
// Create a URL from the string
NSURL *attachmentURL = [[NSURLComponents componentsWithString:attachmentURLString] URL];

...

// Initialize a nil NSError
NSError *error = nil;
// Pass a pointer to the error
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:attachmentURL options:0 error:&error];

if (fileData == nil) {
    // 'error' should now contain a non-nil value.
    // Use this information to handle the error somehow
}
```

Comment: Thanks Charles! [Here's a link to the code](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail/blob/master/RNMail/RNMail.m) would you mind including the modifications in your answer? As I said, I'm not very proficient with objective c

Comment: I'm not going to rewrite your code for you, if that's what you're asking. That's your job. But it's simple enough; just change the call to use the one that returns an error, and then check what that error is.

Comment: No, not asking you to rewrite the code (which isn't my code to begin with). I'm just not sure how to do this bit... create an NSError variable ahead of time, assign it to nil, pass a pointer to the error as the third parameter to -dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:, and then check the error if the method returns nil

Comment: There ya go. Enjoy

Comment: In Objective-C, when you have methods that take multiple parameters, you put one of the parameters after each of the colons (`:`). Also you need a `&` before the error in order to pass a pointer. See my edit.

Comment: I would also consider getting a book on Objective-C and reading it before working with any more Objective-C code directly. The C family of languages make it very easy to shoot yourself in the foot if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Ha, for sure. I wasn't actually planning on having to dig in this deep, but you know... problems must be solved. I do understand the basics, but just the very basics and have little practical experience. I guess I know just enough to shoot myself in the foot, haha. Thanks for your help. I'm working through  your advice now.

Comment: on the NSURL line, Xcode now complains that `No visible @interface for 'NSURLComponents' declares the selector 'url'`

Comment: Oh whoops, I've been doing too much Swift lately. In Objective-C it's spelled with upper-case letters. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for your help! It worked great.